# "second communication we have sent" or "second communication we had sent"?

Tags: tense, past-tense, error

> This is the second communication we have sent and we are much surprised at receiving no answer.

My book says NO ERROR.

But "we have sent" should be "we had sent", **correct me** if I'm wrong.

Answer (score 1):

This is the second communication we have sent and we are very surprised at receiving no answer.

The sentence is grammatically correct to be in the present.  Look at it he following sentence in the past:

This was the second communication we had sent and we were very surprised at receiving no answer. You use the past perfect to refer to an action that happened before another action in the past.